# Is it possible to reference specific version of assembly via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, .net-4.5

A colleague of mine wrote quite questionable piece of code some time ago, and eventually it got broken. Here's simplified sample:

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
Type _mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter"); //getting a reference to internal class

//create an instance of System.Net.Mail.MailWriter storing it into _mailWriter variable
//It's internal, but for now it still works

MethodInfo _sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

//calling non-public method resulting in app crash
_sendMethod.Invoke(
    message,
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
    null,
    new object[] { _mailWriter, true },
    null);
```

After some investigation it turned out that on my development machine there are indeed two parameters of `MailMessage.Send` method:

```
System.Net.Mime.BaseWriter writer
Boolean sendEnvelope
```

Hovewer, our QA engineers have installed VisualStudio 2012 recently, and got .NET 4.5 installed. So, when QA people try to run the application, they got `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException`. And, it looks like `MailMessage.Send` got third parameter in .NET 4.5:

```
System.Net.Mime.BaseWriter writer
Boolean sendEnvelope
Boolean allowUnicode
```

Of course we are to re-implement this piece of code to stop using non-public interfaces. Hovewer, we are on a tight schedule with a project, so we can't afford it right now.

So, here is a question: are there any ways to reference older (e.g. .NET 4.0) version of the assembly via reflection?

Comment: Why not just force the target framework to .NET 4.0 on the projects?

Comment: It's forced to 3.5. Unfortunately it appears that late binding via reflection does not take it into account.

Comment: Nice real world example of why this kind of code stinks +1.

Comment: Like @WouterdeKort says, you need to pass a fully qualified type name to `Assembly.GetType` to get he specific version your are interested in, since there may be, and in fact are, several versions installed side-by-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of loading the Assembly with `typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly` you can load the assembly with `Assembly.Load(AssemblyName)`.

`AssemblyName` describes an assembly's unique identity in full. For example:

```
ExampleAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=a5d015c7d5a0b012
```

You can specify versioning information in your full assembly name.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx) is the MSDN documentation with more examples.

Comment: That's perfectly right, but unfortunately it does not solve the underlying problem. The method extracted from 4.0 version on QA box still has three parameters. Thank you for answering, anyway :)

Comment: I can't make this Assembly.Load work. If I manually change the version number (while debugging) into 2.0.0.0 then version 1.0.0.0 loaded nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

To get specific, do this

```
var systemNet35 = Assembly.Load(
    @"System.Net, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL");

Type _mailWriterType = systemNet35.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
```

---

Of course, this will only work with .Net 3.5 installed.